# Is NS_SWIFT_NAME reserved to Factory methods?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm working on a library written in Objective-C and I would like to make it as "Swifty" as possible when bridged on Swift.

For instance, an Objective-C method with this definition

```
-(void)logProductWithId:(NSString *) productId productName:(NSString*) productName;
```

is automatically translated to this Swift function

```
func logProductWithId(productId: String, productName: String)
```

Is it a good habit to use the `NS_SWIFT_NAME` macro to get rid of the "With":

```
-(void)logProductWithId:(NSString *) productId productName:(NSString*) productName NS_SWIFT_NAME( logProduct(identifier:name:) )
```

which is then translated in swift to

```
func logProduct(identifier productId: String, name productName: String)
```

I see some [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966740/only-factor-methods-can-have-swift-name-attribute-mapbox/38985244#38985244) mentioning that `NS_SWIFT_NAME` is available only for factory methods. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) mentions only factory methods as example but does not explicitly say that about a restriction on `NS_SWIFT_NAME`

Comment: As per the below documentation, `NS_SWIFT_NAME` is not restricted to factory methods
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/renaming_objective-c_apis_for_swift

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no clear restriction in Apple's documentation as far as I can find.
Let's make it a try.

A sample project including this code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
-(void)logProductWithId:(NSString *) productId productName:(NSString*) productName NS_SWIFT_NAME( logProduct(identifier:name:) );

@end
```

Compiles successfully, and you can see its generated interface as:

```
import Foundation

open class MyClass : NSObject {

    open func logProduct(identifier productId: String!, name productName: String!)
}
```

No problem. Maybe you need some other condition to get "Only factory methods can have 'swift_name' attribute" error, which I have not revealed yet.

Seems `NS_SWIFT_NAME` is not reserved only for factory methods. And better use it to make your Objective-C code more Swift-friendly. And please do not forget to put nullability attributes.

Comment: Yes I have the nullability attributes. I just tried to compile on XCode 6 where the macro is not defined at all so I added a compatibility where I defined it as `#define NS_SWIFT_NAME(_)`